# Using asfreq shows only one ticker at the time

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem with .asfreq part of DataFrame pandas. I have stockdata in files named by ticker of stock. The file with data looks like this:

```
uri:/instrument/1.0/AAPL/chartdata;type=quote;range=1d/csv
ticker:aapl
Company-Name:Apple Inc.
Exchange-Name:NMS
unit:MIN
timezone:EST
currency:USD
gmtoffset:-18000
previous_close:114.6300
Timestamp:1417617000,1417640400
labels:1417618800,1417622400,1417626000,1417629600,1417633200,1417636800,1417640400
values:Timestamp,close,high,low,open,volume
close:115.1500,116.2500
high:115.2200,116.3500
low:115.1100,116.2000
open:115.1425,116.2450
volume:13400,3646700
1417617011,115.7498,115.8100,115.5707,115.7150,1622500
1417617060,115.6300,115.7500,115.5000,115.7300,284000
1417617179,115.3990,115.6600,115.3600,115.6500,349600
1417617180,115.6050,115.6400,115.3700,115.3990,300400
1417617299,115.7099,115.7700,115.6000,115.6401,279200
…
```

I have function that picks up all tickers (for example [AAPL,NGF15]) and pull-out type of data (for example - ‘close’) from time to time (for example - ['2014-12-03 15:29:00','2014-12-03 16:31:00' ]) and update it in nested dictionary called data. After i call function nested dictionary looks like  this:

**{'AAPL': {'2014-12-03 16:03:00': '115.4200', '2014-12-03 15:31:00': '115.6300', '2014-12-03 15:51:00': '116.1100', '2014-12-03 16:08:00': ‘115.4100’…},’NGF15': {'2014-12-03 16:02:52': '3.8170', '2014-12-03 16:14:58': '3.8000', '2014-12-03 15:53:58': '3.8010', '2014-12-03 15:33:59': '3.7930', '2014-12-03 15:59:58': '3.8110', '2014-12-03 16:15:00': ‘3.8040’,…}}**

Then code is like this:

```
a=DataFrame(data=data)
a.index.name = 'vrime'
```

DataFrame looks like this :

```
                          AAPL   NGF15
vrime                                
2014-12-03 15:29:59       NaN  3.7870
2014-12-03 15:30:11  115.7498     NaN
2014-12-03 15:30:54       NaN  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:31:00  115.6300     NaN
2014-12-03 15:31:57       NaN  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:32:58       NaN  3.7920
…
2014-12-03 16:21:59  115.5900  3.8090
…
```

So I want to change freq of data for of every 15 sec that price at given time (like 15:30:15) is last price for every ticker.

```
a.index = pd.to_datetime(a.index)
print a.asfreq('15s', method=‘pad',how = {'2014-12-03 15:30:00','2014-12-03 16:30:00'})
```

so my result look like this:

```
                          AAPL   NGF15
2014-12-03 15:29:59       NaN  3.7870
2014-12-03 15:30:14  115.7498     NaN
2014-12-03 15:30:29  115.7498     NaN
2014-12-03 15:30:44  115.7498     NaN
2014-12-03 15:30:59       NaN  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:31:14  115.6300     NaN
2014-12-03 15:31:29  115.6300     NaN
2014-12-03 15:31:44  115.6300     NaN
2014-12-03 15:31:59       NaN  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:32:14       NaN  3.7880
```

It dosent start from 15:30:00 and shows only one ticker at the time. What seems to be the problem?

This is what i want:

```
                        AAPL   NGF15
2014-12-03 15:30:15  115.7498  3.7870
2014-12-03 15:30:30  115.7498  3.7870
2014-12-03 15:30:45  115.7498  3.7870
2014-12-03 15:31:00  115.6300  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:31:15  115.6300  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:31:30  115.6300  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:31:45  115.6300  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:32:00  115.6300  3.7880
2014-12-03 15:32:15  115.6300  3.7880
```

Thank you in advance! Sorry if bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) for `DataFrame.asfreq()` says that the how keyword works "for PeriodIndex only".

`asfreq()` is just a wrapper for `resample()`. Something like `resample('15s', fill_method='pad')` should work. Using some abbreviated data from the above:

```
In [49]: data
Out[49]:
                         0    1
2014-12-03 15:29:59    NaN  3.7
2014-12-03 15:30:11  115.7  NaN
2014-12-03 15:30:54    NaN  3.8
2014-12-03 15:31:00  115.6  NaN

[4 rows x 2 columns]

In [50]: data.resample('15s', fill_method='pad')
Out[50]:
                         0    1
2014-12-03 15:29:45    NaN  3.7
2014-12-03 15:30:00  115.7  3.7
2014-12-03 15:30:15  115.7  3.7
2014-12-03 15:30:30  115.7  3.7
2014-12-03 15:30:45  115.7  3.8
2014-12-03 15:31:00  115.6  3.8
```

If you want to start at 15:30:00, you can drop the first row from the DataFrame.

Comment: That is correct. This is my final code: `a=DataFrame(data=data,dtype=float)` and `print a.resample('15Min', fill_method='pad')
`